# Join two csv recordsets

Tags: sql, vba, csv

I create two separate recordsets but I can't connect them.

Problem is the last SQL.
Those records will have over 100k records so pasting it to form is just too long.
I want to connect it in one record by using Date and time columns.

```vb
Sub aaa()
   
    Dim RS_full As Object
    Dim Rs_FLOAT As Object
    Dim Rs_STRING As Object
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim DataBase
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim n As Byte
    Dim k As Byte
    Dim FL As String
    Dim ST As String
    
    Set Rs_FLOAT = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set cN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set Rs_STRING = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set RS_full = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Set DataBase = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    'DataBase.Show
    Database_Name = "C:\PRIVATE\"
    
    FL = "[kkk(2019).csv]"
    ST = "[aaa.csv]"
    cN.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                   "Data Source=" & Database_Name & ";" & _
                   "Extended Properties=""text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1;""")
    Rs_FLOAT.ActiveConnection = cN
    SQLStr = "select * from " & FL
    Rs_FLOAT.Open SQLStr, cN, 3, 1
    Rs_STRING.ActiveConnection = cN
    SQLStr = "select * from " & ST
    Rs_STRING.Open SQLStr, cN, 3, 1
    
    ' INNER JOIN PROBLEM....................................
    
    'SQLStr = "select * from " & ST & "," & FL
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM " & FL & " INNER JOIN " & ST & " ON " & "kkk(2019).Time = " & "[aaa.csv].Time Where kkk(2019).Time = " & "[aaa.csv].Time "
    RS_full.Open SQLStr, cN, 3, 1

    cN.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You can query both CSVs in same SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you want!
Changed the filenames, updated the SQL and created a procedure to write the recordsets to the sheets 1, 2 and 3 (result).

```
Option Explicit

Sub join_csv_files()
    Dim RS_full As Object
    Dim Rs_FLOAT As Object
    Dim Rs_STRING As Object
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim DataBase
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim n As Byte
    Dim k As Byte
    Dim FL As String
    Dim ST As String
    
    Set Rs_FLOAT = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set Rs_STRING = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set RS_full = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    Set DataBase = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    ' File Path
    Database_Name = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    
    ' Filenames
    FL = "File1.csv"
    ST = "File2.csv"
    
    cn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                   "Data Source=" & Database_Name & ";" & _
                   "Extended Properties=""text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1;""")
                   
    ' Write File1 to sheet1
    Rs_FLOAT.ActiveConnection = cn
    SQLStr = "select * from " & FL
    Rs_FLOAT.Open SQLStr, cn, 3, 1
    Call RecordSetToWorksheet(Sheet1, Rs_FLOAT)
    
    ' Write File2 to sheet2
    Rs_STRING.ActiveConnection = cn
    SQLStr = "select * from " & ST
    Rs_STRING.Open SQLStr, cn, 3, 1
    Call RecordSetToWorksheet(Sheet2, Rs_STRING)
    
    ' SQL
    SQLStr = ""
    SQLStr = SQLStr & "SELECT T1.*, T2.Status "
    SQLStr = SQLStr & "FROM "
    SQLStr = SQLStr & FL & " as T1 INNER JOIN "
    SQLStr = SQLStr & ST & " as T2 "
    SQLStr = SQLStr & "ON T1.Time = T2.Time"
    Debug.Print SQLStr
    
    ' Write result to sheet3
    RS_full.Open SQLStr, cn, 3, 1
    Call RecordSetToWorksheet(Sheet3, RS_full)
    
    cn.Close
End Sub

Sub RecordSetToWorksheet(objSheet As Worksheet, objRecordSet As Object)
    Dim i As Long
    With objSheet
        .Cells.Delete
        For i = 1 To objRecordSet.Fields.Count
            .Cells(1, i).Value = objRecordSet.Fields(i - 1).Name
        Next
        .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset objRecordSet
        .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```vb
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, dbName

dbName = "C:\Excel\SQL"

cn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
           "Data Source='" & dbName & "';" & _
           "Extended Properties=""text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1;""")

Set rs = cn.Execute(" select a.*, b.* from [File1.csv] a " & _
                    " inner join [File2.csv] b on a.TheDate = b.TheDate2 ")

Sheet1.UsedRange.ClearContents
Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

cn.Close
```